# Custom methods in laravel 4 controllers

Tags: php, methods, routes, laravel-4, controllers

I may be misunderstanding how Laravel works or maybe I missed something in the troves of documents I've poured over, and for that I apologize in advance.

Lets say I create a new controller using artisan

```
php artisan controller:make FooController --path /var/www/app/controllers/admin
```

and I set my routes:

```
 Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth.admin'), function()
 {
    Route::any('/',           'App\Controllers\Admin\IndexController@index');
    Route::resource('foo',    'App\Controllers\Admin\FooController');
 }
```

Then in my controller I'll have methods for index(),create(),update(), etc. right?

What if i want a method called activate() in my FooController? It could look like this:

```
public function activate($id){
    return "activated";
}
```

Now I put a link in my index.blade.php file

```
 <a href="{{ URL::route('admin.foo.activate', $foo->id) }}">Activate</a>
```

Why does this not work? I get:

*`Unable to generate a URL for the named route "admin.foo.activate" as such route does not exist.`*

Maybe I'm not good enough with routes but this is really frustrating.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how i solved it:

I needed to user Route::get

```
Route::get('admin/foo/activate/{id}',    'App\Controllers\Admin\foo@activate');
```

then my link needed to user the namespace:

```
Url::action(App\Controllers\Admin\Foo@activate,$foo->id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
URL::action('admin.foo@activate')
```

you are trying to route to /admin/foo/activate (for which indeed there is no route defined).
Otherwise you can also define a route:

```
Route::controller('foo/activate/{id}',    'App\Controllers\Admin\FooController@action');
```

and work with your solution, but I think the first option is better.

Comment: Neither worked. The first option returned unknown action. the second threw the class does not exist exception. I know the controller is working correctly because if I remove the @action from it, it will load the index.

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly a bit cleaner if you name the route in app/routes.php, i.e.

`Route::get('admin/foo/activate/{id}', [
        'as' => 'admin.foo.activate',
        'uses' => 'App\Controllers\Admin\foo@activate']);`

then you can call via

`<a href="{{ URL::route('admin.foo.activate', $foo->id) }}">Activate</a>`

or even

`{{ URL::link_to_route('admin.foo.activate', 'Activate', [$foo->id]) }}`